# Best way to build a wizard driven order capture app in grails

Tags: grails

I am building an order capture system that uses a wizard approach to capture customer orders and add them to a shopping basket. Data for the products available will come from external systems via web service calls. There will also be a need for some kind of manual workflow features for when a customer needs a sales assistant to review an order and apply a discount

I am planning to implement this in grails (is this a good choice)...can anybody recommend any plugins/approaches to implement the wizard and workflow capabilities in grails?

cheers

Comment: This is a bit broad for Stack Overflow. If you face an actual specific implementation problem (beyond selecting a starting point), please feel free to ask here.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Spring WebFlow](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.5%20Web%20Flow)!  At one point it was actually built into grails and it is developed by the same company that now owns Grails (Spring).  It seems like what your looking for!

Comment: +1 for WebFlow, you can read more about it in [the latest documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.5%20Web%20Flow)